# Storing route in PostGIS Database

Tags: postgis, geojson, line, route, open-source-routing-machine

I am trying to save few routes created by OSRM which is in Polyline or GeoJSON format in my PostGIS Database.

How can I save the data in such a format which I can use to search with coordinates interesting those routes later?

Providing sample route data from OSRM as below.

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "legs": [
        {
          "steps": [
            {
              "intersections": [
                {
                  "out": 0,
                  "entry": [
                    true
                  ],
                  "bearings": [
                    30
                  ],
                  "location": [
                    76.308206,
                    10.024981
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "driving_side": "right",
              "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                  [
                    76.308206,
                    10.024981
                  ],
                  [
                    76.308636,
                    10.025709
                  ],
                  [
                    76.309289,
                    10.026855
                  ],
                  [
                    76.309785,
                    10.027748
                  ],
                  [
                    76.309934,
                    10.028019
                  ]
                ],
                "type": "LineString"
              },
              "mode": "driving",
              "duration": 21.6,
              "maneuver": {
                "bearing_after": 30,
                "location": [
                  76.308206,
                  10.024981
                ],
                "bearing_before": 0,
                "type": "depart"
              },
              "weight": 21.6,
              "distance": 387.3,
              "name": "Edapally Overbridge"
            },
            {
              "intersections": [
                {
                  "out": 0,
                  "location": [
                    76.309934,
                    10.028019
                  ],
                  "bearings": [
                    29,
                    208,
                    214
                  ],
                  "entry": [
                    true,
                    false,
                    false
                  ],
                  "in": 1
                }
              ],
              "driving_side": "right",
              "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                  [
                    76.309934,
                    10.028019
                  ],
                  [
                    76.310291,
                    10.028655
                  ],
                  [
                    76.31042,
                    10.028893
                  ],
                  [
                    76.310449,
                    10.028931
                  ],
                  [
                    76.310502,
                    10.029025
                  ],
                  [
                    76.31058,
                    10.029146
                  ]
                ],
                "type": "LineString"
              },
              "mode": "driving",
              "duration": 10.1,
              "maneuver": {
                "bearing_after": 28,
                "type": "new name",
                "modifier": "straight",
                "bearing_before": 28,
                "location": [
                  76.309934,
                  10.028019
                ]
              },
              "ref": "NH544",
              "weight": 10.1,
              "distance": 144,
              "name": "Salem-Kochi-Kanyakumari Highway"
            },
            {
              "intersections": [
                {
                  "out": 2,
                  "location": [
                    76.31058,
                    10.029146
                  ],
                  "bearings": [
                    30,
                    210,
                    330
                  ],
                  "entry": [
                    true,
                    false,
                    true
                  ],
                  "in": 1
                }
              ],
              "driving_side": "right",
              "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                  [
                    76.31058,
                    10.029146
                  ],
                  [
                    76.310309,
                    10.029757
                  ]
                ],
                "type": "LineString"
              },
              "mode": "driving",
              "duration": 6.6,
              "maneuver": {
                "bearing_after": 336,
                "type": "turn",
                "modifier": "left",
                "bearing_before": 29,
                "location": [
                  76.31058,
                  10.029146
                ]
              },
              "weight": 6.6,
              "distance": 74.2,
              "name": "V P Marakkar Road"
            },
            {
              "intersections": [
                {
                  "in": 0,
                  "entry": [
                    true
                  ],
                  "bearings": [
                    156
                  ],
                  "location": [
                    76.310309,
                    10.029757
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "driving_side": "right",
              "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                  [
                    76.310309,
                    10.029757
                  ],
                  [
                    76.310309,
                    10.029757
                  ]
                ],
                "type": "LineString"
              },
              "mode": "driving",
              "duration": 0,
              "maneuver": {
                "bearing_after": 0,
                "location": [
                  76.310309,
                  10.029757
                ],
                "bearing_before": 336,
                "type": "arrive"
              },
              "weight": 0,
              "distance": 0,
              "name": "V P Marakkar Road"
            }
          ],
          "distance": 605.5,
          "duration": 38.3,
          "summary": "Edapally Overbridge, Salem-Kochi-Kanyakumari Highway",
          "weight": 38.3
        }
      ],
      "distance": 605.5,
      "duration": 38.3,
      "weight_name": "routability",
      "weight": 38.3
    }
  ],
  "waypoints": [
    {
      "hint": "f_k2gP___38EAAAAOQAAAK4AAACjAAAAnOIIQSqbukKrDJxDxjmSQwQAAAA5AAAArgAAAKMAAADfAQAA7l6MBBX4mADNXowEKPiYAAYA7wHhixOC",
      "distance": 4.18389,
      "name": "Edapally Overbridge",
      "location": [
        76.308206,
        10.024981
      ]
    },
    {
      "hint": "HykDgHh7VoBCAAAALgAAAAAAAAAAAAAA46OTQnWPR0IAAAAAAAAAAEIAAAAuAAAAAAAAAAAAAADfAQAAJWeMBL0KmQAkZ4wEvQqZAAAADxXhixOC",
      "distance": 0.109632,
      "name": "V P Marakkar Road",
      "location": [
        76.310309,
        10.029757
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

GeoJSON sample

```
{"code":"Ok","waypoints":[{"hint":"ka-TgFyvk4AYAAAABQAAAAAAAAAgAAAASjFaQdLNK0AAAAAAsPePQQwAAAADAAAAAAAAABAAAAAt5QAA_kvMAKlYIQM8TMwArVghAwAA7wqoiYqZ","distance":4.231666,"location":[13.388798,52.517033],"name":"Friedrichstraße"},{"hint":"xLsWgCoshYUGAAAACgAAAAAAAAB2AAAAW7-PQOKcyEAAAAAApq6DQgYAAAAKAAAAAAAAAHYAAAAt5QAAf27MABiJIQOCbswA_4ghAwAAXwWoiYqZ","distance":2.789393,"location":[13.397631,52.529432],"name":"Torstraße"},{"hint":"0bgWgP___38fAAAAUQAAACYAAAAeAAAAsowKQkpQX0Lx6yZCvsQGQh8AAABRAAAAJgAAAB4AAAAt5QAASufMAOdwIQNL58wA03AhAwMAvxCoiYqZ","distance":2.226595,"location":[13.428554,52.523239],"name":"Platz der Vereinten Nationen"}],"routes":[{"legs":[{"steps":[{"intersections":[{"out":0,"entry":[true],"location":[13.388798,52.517033],"bearings":[355]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,false,false,true],"location":[13.388779,52.517155],"bearings":[0,90,180,270]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false,true],"location":[13.388643,52.518027],"bearings":[0,90,180,270]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false,true,false],"location":[13.388544,52.518716],"bearings":[30,90,180,270,315]},{"out":0,"in":1,"entry":[true,false,true],"location":[13.388308,52.520336],"bearings":[0,180,270]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false,true],"location":[13.388024,52.52175],"bearings":[0,60,180,225]},{"out":0,"in":1,"entry":[true,false,true],"location":[13.387885,52.522524],"bearings":[0,180,225]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false],"location":[13.387799,52.523401],"bearings":[0,90,180]},{"out":0,"in":1,"lanes":[{"valid":false,"indications":["none"]},{"valid":false,"indications":["left"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["straight"]}],"entry":[true,false,true],"location":[13.387748,52.523877],"bearings":[0,180,270]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false],"location":[13.3877,52.524433],"bearings":[0,90,180]},{"out":3,"in":1,"entry":[true,false,false,true],"location":[13.387337,52.526239],"bearings":[105,165,300,345]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,false,false,false],"location":[13.387283,52.526386],"bearings":[0,105,165,255]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"mfp_I__vpAYBO@K@[BuBRgBLK@UBMMC?AAKAe@FyBTC@E?IDKDA@K@]BUBSBA?E@E@A@KFUBK@mAL{CZQ@qBRUBmAFc@@}@Fu@DG?a@B[@qAF_AJ[D_E`@SBO@ODA@UDA?]JC?uBNE?OAKA","duration":129.2,"distance":1135.7,"name":"Friedrichstraße","weight":130.4,"mode":"driving","maneuver":{"bearing_after":355,"bearing_before":0,"type":"depart","location":[13.388798,52.517033]}},{"intersections":[{"out":0,"in":1,"entry":[true,false,true,true],"location":[13.387215,52.527166],"bearings":[75,180,255,330]},{"out":0,"in":1,"entry":[true,false,true],"location":[13.389147,52.527549],"bearings":[75,255,345]},{"out":0,"in":1,"entry":[true,false,true],"location":[13.391396,52.528032],"bearings":[75,255,330]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false],"location":[13.392425,52.528233],"bearings":[75,165,255]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false,true],"location":[13.393814,52.528526],"bearings":[75,135,255,315]},{"out":0,"in":1,"entry":[true,false,true],"location":[13.395724,52.528996],"bearings":[75,255,345]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false,true],"location":[13.397565,52.529429],"bearings":[90,180,255,345]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"yer_IcuupACa@AI]mCCUE[AK[iCWqB[{Bk@sE_@_DAICSAOIm@AIQuACOQyAG[Gc@]wBw@aFKu@y@oFCMAOIm@?K","duration":122.3,"distance":749,"name":"Torstraße","weight":122.3,"mode":"driving","maneuver":{"bearing_after":71,"location":[13.387215,52.527166],"type":"turn","bearing_before":4,"modifier":"right"}},{"intersections":[{"in":0,"entry":[true],"location":[13.397631,52.529432],"bearings":[266]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"}sr_IevwpA","duration":0,"distance":0,"name":"Torstraße","weight":0,"mode":"driving","maneuver":{"bearing_after":0,"bearing_before":86,"type":"arrive","location":[13.397631,52.529432]}}],"weight":252.7,"distance":1884.7,"summary":"Friedrichstraße, Torstraße","duration":251.5},{"steps":[{"intersections":[{"out":0,"entry":[true],"location":[13.397631,52.529432],"bearings":[85]},{"out":0,"in":2,"lanes":[{"valid":true,"indications":["left"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["straight"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["straight","right"]}],"entry":[true,true,false,false],"location":[13.401337,52.529605],"bearings":[90,165,270,345]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,false,true],"location":[13.401541,52.529618],"bearings":[90,165,285]},{"out":1,"in":3,"lanes":[{"valid":false,"indications":["left"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["straight"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["straight","right"]}],"entry":[true,true,true,false],"location":[13.409405,52.528711],"bearings":[30,105,210,285]},{"out":0,"in":2,"lanes":[{"valid":true,"indications":["straight"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["straight","right"]}],"entry":[true,true,false],"location":[13.409967,52.528591],"bearings":[105,165,285]},{"out":0,"in":2,"lanes":[{"valid":true,"indications":["straight"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["straight","right"]}],"entry":[true,false,false,false],"location":[13.410145,52.528553],"bearings":[105,150,285,330]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false],"location":[13.411852,52.528201],"bearings":[120,210,285]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"}sr_IevwpAAQ?KIuDQmHE}BBQ?Q?OCq@?I?IASAg@OuF?OAi@?c@@c@Du@r@cH@U@I@G@K?E~@kJRyBf@uE@KFi@RaBBMFc@Da@@ETaC@QJ{@Ny@Ha@RiAfBuJF]DOh@yAHSf@aADIR_@","duration":202.6,"distance":1272.3,"name":"Torstraße","weight":202.6,"mode":"driving","maneuver":{"bearing_after":85,"bearing_before":0,"type":"depart","location":[13.397631,52.529432]}},{"intersections":[{"out":1,"in":3,"lanes":[{"valid":false,"indications":["left"]},{"valid":false,"indications":["left"]},{"valid":false,"indications":["straight"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["straight"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["straight","right"]}],"entry":[false,true,true,false],"location":[13.415405,52.526922],"bearings":[30,135,210,315]},{"out":0,"in":3,"lanes":[{"valid":true,"indications":["left"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["left"]},{"valid":false,"indications":["straight"]},{"valid":false,"indications":["straight"]},{"valid":false,"indications":["straight"]}],"entry":[true,true,false,false],"location":[13.415657,52.52677],"bearings":[30,135,210,315]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"gdr_Iie{pA\\q@w@y@","duration":12,"distance":60.5,"name":"","weight":12,"mode":"driving","maneuver":{"bearing_after":133,"location":[13.415405,52.526922],"type":"turn","bearing_before":133,"modifier":"left"}},{"intersections":[{"out":0,"in":2,"lanes":[{"valid":false,"indications":["left"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["straight"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["straight"]}],"entry":[true,false,false,true],"location":[13.415945,52.527047],"bearings":[30,120,210,315]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"aer_Iuh{pAe@a@CCUQaCkB{@y@GESO","duration":18.2,"distance":177.4,"name":"Prenzlauer Allee","weight":18.2,"mode":"driving","maneuver":{"bearing_after":26,"location":[13.415945,52.527047],"type":"new name","bearing_before":30,"modifier":"straight"}},{"intersections":[{"out":1,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false,false],"location":[13.417166,52.528458],"bearings":[30,90,210,315]},{"out":1,"in":3,"entry":[false,true,true,false],"location":[13.423592,52.528206],"bearings":[45,120,225,285]},{"out":1,"in":3,"entry":[true,true,false,false],"location":[13.423868,52.528136],"bearings":[45,120,210,300]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"{mr_Iip{pA?_@?C?[IoCIgDMsEAYOkEAQ@Yj@kENg@ZyBBIHm@FY@GBUJk@JmA?c@?QAQG]","duration":55,"distance":547.1,"name":"Prenzlauer Berg","weight":55,"mode":"driving","maneuver":{"bearing_after":85,"location":[13.417166,52.528458],"type":"turn","bearing_before":28,"modifier":"right"}},{"intersections":[{"out":1,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false,true],"location":[13.424993,52.528068],"bearings":[60,150,255,345]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false],"location":[13.425842,52.527621],"bearings":[120,225,300]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false],"location":[13.428041,52.526565],"bearings":[135,225,315]},{"out":0,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false],"location":[13.429315,52.525737],"bearings":[135,225,315]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"mkr_Iea}pALKDEDCHOL]FO^uA@GTu@La@`A_DJ[pAgCJSlAwBJSf@{@b@w@dAqBHQZq@LMLKRI","duration":47.9,"distance":509.2,"name":"Friedenstraße","weight":47.9,"mode":"driving","maneuver":{"bearing_after":153,"location":[13.424993,52.528068],"type":"turn","bearing_before":67,"modifier":"right"}},{"intersections":[{"out":1,"in":2,"entry":[true,true,false],"location":[13.430405,52.524964],"bearings":[135,180,345]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"_xq_Iac~pAFAL?J@HBFBp@XPHh@TTJNFTRNFd@N\\HF@J@J@","duration":20.9,"distance":196.4,"name":"Platz der Vereinten Nationen","weight":20.9,"mode":"driving","maneuver":{"bearing_after":174,"location":[13.430405,52.524964],"type":"new name","bearing_before":163,"modifier":"straight"}},{"intersections":[{"out":3,"in":0,"lanes":[{"valid":false,"indications":["left"]},{"valid":false,"indications":["straight","left"]},{"valid":false,"indications":["straight"]},{"valid":true,"indications":["straight","right"]}],"entry":[false,false,true,true],"location":[13.429678,52.523269],"bearings":[0,90,180,270]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"mmq_Io~}pA@V?N@rA@dB","duration":6.9,"distance":76.1,"name":"Platz der Vereinten Nationen","weight":6.9,"mode":"driving","maneuver":{"bearing_after":267,"location":[13.429678,52.523269],"type":"continue","bearing_before":184,"modifier":"right"}},{"intersections":[{"in":0,"entry":[true],"location":[13.428554,52.523239],"bearings":[88]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"gmq_Imw}pA","duration":0,"distance":0,"name":"Platz der Vereinten Nationen","weight":0,"mode":"driving","maneuver":{"bearing_after":0,"bearing_before":268,"type":"arrive","location":[13.428554,52.523239]}}],"weight":363.5,"distance":2839.1,"summary":"Torstraße, Friedenstraße","duration":363.5}],"weight_name":"routability","weight":616.2,"distance":4723.8,"duration":615}]}
```

Comment: This isn't GeoJSON, but if you had a route in a GeoJSON of multiline geometry, you could simply store the geometry in a geometry\geography column. Are you asking how to write data into PostgreSQL or how would such data be saved?

Comment: This is not GeoJSON.Its polyline... It will return both Polyline aswell GeoJSON. If its GeoJSON. How can I save it to POSTGIS as geometry.

Comment: Updated query with GeoJSON.  Path to sample data is: http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407;13.428555,52.523219?overview=false&steps=true

Comment: My need is to save this data in POSTGIS and check coordinates interesting the routes saved. Also need to try to create a buffered polygon region out of it.

Comment: Since you asked a very general question, the answer you already have from @stefanbrand should do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PostGIS driver of OGR](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html#examples), e.g.:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:dbname=mydb route.geojson
```